# how to fix curl removing other dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, nodejs, curl

I wanted to install node js on Ubuntu 18.04. I did from the official repository.

```
sudo apt install nodejs npm.
```

Then found the version is 8. So I wanted to update it following the official doc.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

It said curl is not installed. So I installed curl.
`sudo apt install curl`.

And I got this message.

```
dpkg: libcurl3:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 opera-stable depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) | libcurl4 (>= 7.58.0); however:
  Package libcurl3:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libcurl4 is not installed.
 atom depends on libcurl3 | libcurl4; however:
  Package libcurl3:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libcurl4 is not installed.

Removing libcurl3:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl4:amd64.
(Reading database ... 305616 files and directories currently installed.)
```

How to fix it now?

Comment: Trying to mix newer packages on an older OS doesn't work - it introduces *version conflicts*, as you have discovered. For compatibility with newer software, use a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 isn't 18.04 the latest LTS?

Comment: Besides, what are the odds that libcurl4 won't work if I install it as the error message suggested?

Comment: @Bluebug It's the latest LTS release but more than one year old. There were 18.10 and 19.04 after that. The package you're trying to install is newer than the one included with 18.04.

Comment: The purpose of an LTS is workflow stability (not system stability) - the software doesn't change for five years, which enterprise users tend to like. Since you seem to want newer software, perhaps an interim release of Ubuntu (like 19.04) with newer software might be a better choice.

Comment: Also, looks like you could have avoided a lot of the problem by NOT using apt's `-y` flag. You disabled an important safeguard there.

Comment: Ah my bad. Anyways so what are the possible solutions? Upgrade distro or are there workarounds? Update: I just  tried installing libcurl4. Now it says "libcurl4 is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7).
libcurl4 set to manually installed." So I'm confused now.

Comment: Nothing is broken that can be "fixed" - you have created a logic trap, and apt is simply telling you about it. You have two realistic options: You can install 19.04, or you can downgrade nodejs/npm. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Please tell me about the trap I created.  If I leave it as it is, what can happen?